# Поделиться google, кодировка (неправильный tittle, description)

Tags: javascript, share, ya-share2

После нажатия кнопки "поделится, на g+" при создании поста внизу (там где ссылка ), вместо тайтла отображает иероглифы. С остальными кнопками всё хорошо. Менял кодировки разными способами, всеровно без толку.

Вот так выглядит тайтл:
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Кодировка скрипта - utf-8, кодировка сайта тоже - utf-8

```
<script src="//yastatic.net/es5-shims/0.0.2/es5-shims.min.js"charset="utf-8"></script>
<script src="//yastatic.net/share2/share.js" charset="utf-8"></script>
<div class="ya-share2" data-lang="ru" data-services="vkontakte,facebook,odnoklassniki,moimir,gplus,twitter,viber,telegram"></div>
```

Comment: Попробуйте в Win-1252 перекодировать

Comment: Вы хотели написать cp-1251? Ничего не меняется. Результат тот же.

Comment: Кодировка у документа указана и соответствует действительности?

Comment: Да. Сохранил все документы в utf-8 и в мета тегах тоже указал utf-8

Comment: @Roman Укажите ссылку на сайт, пожалуйста. Будем разбираться.

Comment: Вот допустим даже здесь http://u0409377.plsk.regruhosting.ru/index31.html

Comment: На чистом коде всё та же проблема. Возможно проблема от идёт хостера. Сайт на windows IIS. Может быть нужно что-то нужно прописать в web.config, или я чего-то не знаю...Опять же, повторюсь .html сохранён в utf-8.

Comment: @РоманПарадеев Ссылку оставил в теме, проблема всё еще актуальна

Comment: @Roman На указанной выше странице в разметке отсутствует DOCTYPE.

Comment: @РоманПарадеев Это все равно никак не влияет на результат, но всё же добавил в разметку для наглядности

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Скорее всего, не указана кодировка в заголовке ответа `Content-Type`. Например, сервер может отдавать просто `text/html`.

А должно быть так:

```
Content-Type: text/html; charset=UTF-8
```

Comment: Content-Type: text/html
Content-Encoding: gzip
Last-Modified: Wed, 01 Nov 2017 21:45:36 GMT
Accept-Ranges: bytes
ETag: "278b6cc05a53d31:0"
Vary: Accept-Encoding
Server: Microsoft-IIS/10.0
X-Powered-By: ASP.NET
X-Powered-By-Plesk: PleskWin
Date: Wed, 01 Nov 2017 23:04:55 GMT
Content-Length: 464

Comment: Указал глобализацию в web.config на utf-8, и в asp.net. Сервер все равно выдает text/html

Comment: А, всё, разобрался. Спасибо